# 'Bad address' when doing sendto-call to the sockaddr* retrieved by recvfrom

Tags: c++, sockets

```
    struct sockaddr_in  addrSenderOfVideo
    struct sockaddr_in   client_addr;     // Client Internet address
    char* buffer = new char[2];
    int sizeOfBuffer=1050;
    int clientfd;
    char* bufferWithPacketData = new char[sizeOfBuffer];
    extern int                  client_s;        // Client socket 

    if (client_s < 0)
          {
            printf("*** ERROR - socket() failed \n");
          }

           //Client address.
      client_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
      client_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); // IP address to use
      client_addr.sin_port = htons(portNumClient); 

    clientfd = bind(client_s,(const sockaddr*) &client_addr, sizeof(client_addr));
    fprintf (stderr, "inside of listen for new packet<; clientfd is %d",clientfd);

      if (clientfd < 0) 
        {
        fprintf (stderr, "WARNING -1 doing BIND!");

        }


    int n = recvfrom (client_s, bufferWithPacketData, sizeOfBuffer, 0,(struct sockaddr*)&addrSenderOfVideo, &fromlen);

   retcode = sendto(client_s, buffer,  symbol_size, 0,
          (struct sockaddr *)&addrSenderOfVideo, sizeof(addrSenderOfVideo) );
```

When sendto is called, the error '9errno is Bad address' is printed out.
What is the cause of this and how do I resolve this?

The data is received from the sender in the function recvfrom, and `addrSenderOfVideo` contains both a port and an ip-number.
The sender has the ip '127.0.0.1' and this is also the ip that is contained in `addrSenderOfVideo`.

Comment: There are two parameters of `sendto` which are pointers to userspace buffers and could therefore trigger the `EFAULT`: the data buffer and the address. The address points to a local variable of fixed size, so it doesn't seem to be the culprit. So it must be the data buffer. The data buffer points to an array of size 2. You didn't show us how you initialize `symbol_size`. Is `symbol_size` perchance greater than 2?

Comment: @Celada ,
Thanks a lot! Yes, when reusing code, I did the mistake of forgetting to use another size instead of 'symbol_size'. When I changed this size it is now working.
I was looking for the bug in the wrong place... If your post your comment as an answer, I can select it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two parameters of `sendto` which are pointers to userspace buffers and could therefore trigger the `EFAULT`: the data buffer and the address. The address points to a local variable of fixed size, so it doesn't seem to be the culprit. So it must be the data buffer. The data buffer points to an array of size 2. You didn't show us how you initialize `symbol_size`. Is `symbol_size` perchance greater than 2?